# How can I pass the value of setState on Googlemap api function (initialcenter)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-hooks, setstate

I am trying to track the user's location. Here I have put one button and `onclick` I am trying to display the user's location on the google map.
The problem I am facing is on the `initialCenter` where I need to pass the `setState` value from `getCoordinates(position)` function.
[image]

I want to pass the `setstate` value in this `lat` & `lng`.
Anyone??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../User_Map/user_map.css'
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react';

 

class User_Map extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            userAddress: null,
            zoom: 11
        }

        this.getLocation = this.getLocation.bind(this);
        this.getCoordinates = this.getCoordinates.bind(this);
        // this.reverseGeocodeCoordinates = this.reverseGeocodeCoordinates.bind(this);
    }
    
    getLocation(){
        
        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.getCoordinates);
        }
        else{
            alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser')
        }
    }

    getCoordinates(position){
        this.setState({
            latitude: position.coords.latitude,
            longitude: position.coords.longitude
        })

        
      //  this.reverseGeocodeCoordinates();
        // console.log(position)
    }

    // reverseGeocodeCoordinates(){
    //   fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY')
    //   .then(response => response.json())
    //   // .then(data => this.setState({
    //   //   userAddress: data.results[0].formatted_address
    //   // }))
    //   .then(data => console.log(data))
    //   .catch(error => alert(error))
    // }

    handleLocationError(error){
      switch(error.code){
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
          alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.")
          break;
          case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable.")
            break;
            case error.TIMEOUT:
              alert("The request to get user location timed out.")
              break;
              case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                alert("An unknown error occured.")
                break;
                default:
                  alert("An unknown error occured.")
      }
    }
    
 
  render() {
    return (
     <>
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.getLocation}>Find Me</button> 
        <h4>HTML 5 Coordinates</h4>
        <p>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</p>
        <p>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</p>

        <Map google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={14}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude
        }}
        >
 
        <Marker onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
                name={'Current location'} />

        {/* <InfoWindow onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
            <div>
              <h1>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h1>
            </div>
        </InfoWindow> */}
        </Map>


        {/* <h4>Google Maps Reverse Geocoding</h4>
        <p>Address: {this.state.userAddress}</p>
        {
          this.state.latitude && this.state.longitude ?
          <img src={'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false&markers=color:red%7C${this.state.latitude},${this.state.longitude}&key=YOUR_API_KEY'} alt=''/>
          :
          null
        } */}
      </div>
  
    </>
    );
  }
}

// export default User_Map;

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: ("YOUR API KEY")
  })(User_Map)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was facing was in function so for me the below code worked properly.

```
<Map google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={14}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude
        }}
        center={{
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude
        }}
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

I see that you are using `google-maps-react` [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#additional-map-props). Please note that this library has multiple optional props such as `initialCenter` and `center`. `initialCenter` takes an object containing latitude and longitude coordinates. Sets the maps center upon loading while `center` takes an object containing latitude and longitude coordinates. Use this if you want to re-render the map after the initial render.

So if you want to change the center of the map after getting the coordinates from your geolocation, you can pass your state coordinates to the `center` property instead of `initialCenter`. Please see code snippet below:

```
  <Map google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={14}
        initialCenter={{
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude
        }}
        center={{
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude
        }}
        >
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.